# How to customize devise login and signup forms created using the simple_form gem?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I am using devise for authentication in my rails app and I have created the forms using the simple_form gem. I want to customize the login and signup forms using css but can't seem to figure out to target, which class to use and add a line break.

here is what I need to do,

1. Add a line break after the label and move the asterisk after the label.
2. customize the input boxes using css
3. customize the signup button using css

This is how my devise view for signup page looks like,

```
<div class="formwrapper">
<center>
<h1>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name, :label => 'First Name', required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :last_name, :label => 'Last Name', required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :user_name, :label => 'Username', required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Email', required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :password, :label => 'Password', required: true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => 'Confirm Password', required: true %>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. This is simple to do.

In your code change this to

```
    <%= f.input :first_name, :label => 'First Name', required: true, autofocus: true %>
```

THIS :-

```
    <%= f.input :first_name, :label => 'First Name', required: true, autofocus: true , **:class => 'yourcustomclass'** %>
```

Similarly for the other controls.

Answer (score 2):

Since Devise is an engine, all its views are packaged inside the gem. These views will help you get started, but after some time you may want to change them. If this is the case, you just need to invoke the following generator, and it will copy all views to your application:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

If you have more than one Devise model in your application (such as User and Admin), you will notice that Devise uses the same views for all models. Fortunately, Devise offers an easy way to customize views. All you need to do is set:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

inside the config/initializers/devise.rb file.